# Android Audio Question

Tags: android

I have several audio files in the res/raw folder.
When I run the following code I was assuming that just the "sound1" file would be played, instead all of the files in the folder get played one after another, not just "sound1".

```
  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
  try {
    mp.start();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

What am I missing?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds odd.. you are sure your sound is what you think it is?

Comment: Mayra == smart;
Echidna == dumb;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
  static MediaPlayer mpBackground = new MediaPlayer();

  mpBackground = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

  mpBackground.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SoundPool instead if they are short sound clips... I ran into alot of issues using the Mediaplayer for playing short sounds. I store my sounds in the assets folder instead of res/raw... but you can get the same results. Here is some code.

```
private int BUZZ = sound_load("sounds/buzz.mp3");

private SoundPool _sounds = new SoundPool(8, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

private int sound_load(String fname) {
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = am.openFd(fname);
        int sid = _sounds.load(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(),
                fd.getLength(), 1);
        return sid;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return 0;
}

private void sound_play(int sid) {
    _sounds.play(sid, (float) 1.0, (float) 1.0, 0, 0, (float) 1.0);
}
```

Then to play a sound I just call it like this:

```
sound_play(BUZZ);
```